# XSD: Adding attributes to strongly-typed "simple" elements

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

Is there some sensible way to have elements with strongly-typed simple-types and also attributes?

Okay, I have an XSD schema which has a million (er, hundred) elements that might look like this:

```
<xsd:element name="DocumentDescription" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="DocumentDateTime" type="xsd:dateTime" />
<xsd:element name="DocumentSize" type="xsd:int" />
```

That's dandy. However, I really want all of these elements to also have some common attributes on them like, let's say, "format" and "isVisible". i.e. have a schema like:

```
<DocumentDescription isVisible="true">doc description</DocumentDescription>
<DocumentDateTime format="dd/mm/yyyy" isVisible="true">1/1/2008</DocumentDescription>
<DocumentSize format="0.00 KB" isVisible="false">5403</DocumentSize>
```

I could do it manually, and horribly, by adding all such attributes to the XSD when I generate it, something like this:

```
<xsd:element name="DocumentDescription" />
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="format" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:attribute name="isVisible" type="xsd:boolean" />
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="DocumentDateTime" />
   ... etc
```

...but in an ideal world I'd rather define it as a complexType:

```
<xsd:complexType name="customType">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="???">
      <xsd:attribute name="format" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="isVisible" type="xsd:boolean" />
```

...which means I could just do:

```
<xsd:element name="DocumentDescription" type="customType" baseType="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element name="DocumentDateTime" type="customType" baseType="xsd:dateTime" />
<xsd:element name="DocumentSize" type="customType" baseType="xsd:int" />
```

The problem with my "ideal world" code is that:

**a)** I've no valid `<xsd:extension base-"???"`>, since really I don't care what I'm extending; I want to extend all types. Seems like the "xsd:anyType" is appropriate, yet then the element becomes a weakly typed container does it not?

**b)** I can no longer specify the simple type on the `<xsd:element`>, since now the type is the complex "customType" I defined. Hence the imaginary "baseType" attribute I put there...

So can I add attributes to simple types in a non-clunky way? Or do I need to define a dozen complexTypes that are all identical except for the simple type that they extend?

Strongly-typed elements not only describe the data more sensibly, but when I use them for XML mapping in Excel (and this is the whole purpose behind these things), the strong-typing means that Excel sets the cell formatting correctly based on the type.

I'm probably looking at it all the wrong way! Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I have cancelled an edition that consisted in renaming all occurrences of _strongly-type_ with _built-in simple types_ ([W3C wording](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/primer.html#simpleTypesTable)). Such a wording would have helped me to find your question. Now I'm not sure that the edit is worthy, and I'm happy with my comment including this wording, so I can find your question again in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > [quote]could do it manually, and horribly, by
> >     adding all such attributes to the XSD
> >     when I generate it, something like
> >     this:[/quote]

I'm afraid this is your only "proper", XSD-schema compatible way to do it.

XSD can be convoluted to author at times - but it helps keeping things safe :-)

Marc

Comment: Damn! Well, thanks. I might give the dozen identical-except-for-extension-complexTypes a go first though, given the number of elements it will at least make the XSD smaller, albeit ugly!

Comment: @Gavin It is worthy to take a look at the `attributeGroup` suggestion by [C. M. Sperberg-McQueen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14497740/413020) if you are always adding the same set of attributes

Answer (score 4):

It's not entirely clear which aspect of the manual solution you regard as horrible; if it's the idea of having to define *n* different types just because they will need to extend *n* different base types, then you're stuck.

If it's the idea of having to have *n* different declarations for the `format` and `isVisible` attributes, then you might find it less horrible to use a named attribute group to hold those definitions:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="globals">
  <xs:attribute name="format" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="isVisible" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

The declarations of the various complex types you need remain repetitive but are now slightly less verbose:

```
<xs:complexType name="string">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="my:globals"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="dateTime">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:dateTime">
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="my:globals"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="int">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:int">
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="my:globals"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And the declarations of your elements are now slightly simpler than in your 'ideal' case:

```
<xs:element name="DocumentDescription" type="my:string" />
<xs:element name="DocumentDateTime" type="my:dateTime" />
<xs:element name="DocumentSize" type="my:int" />
```

Comment: In XSD 1.1 there is a schema attribute called `defaultAttributes` that applies an attribute group to every complexType unless `defaultAttributesApply` is set to false in that complexType. This doesn't work for simpleTypes but using your great approach you'd have to writte two lines less for every complexType declaration as the extension can be a self closed tag `<xs:extension base="xs:string"/>`

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an XSD is to describe your data.  The purpose of an XSD's type attribute is to describe or define an element.  What you want to do is to change the element's definition.  If you're changing the description change the type.  What you're trying to do is like putting wheels on a thought.  "But I *want* wheels on my thought!"  "Sorry, no can do."