# XSD: How to derive a simpletype both to add a attribute to it and to restrict the acceptable value of it

Tags: xsd

for example 
To validate the following element:

```
 <population class="AAA">100</population >
```

The constraint I want on the text node is that it should be a numeric value, between 1 and 1000.

my idea looks like this but it doen't work

```
 <xsd:element name="population">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="1000"/>        
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:attribute name="class" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

By the way, I do not want to define any more new type.
Can anyone help me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without adding a new type; you can't extend and restrict at the same time.

Comment: I don't think your answer is relevant. The wording of the question implies that the line below `<population>` is there only to clarify the allowed content of the element, not to be part of the document.

Comment: @jasso, I've proposed an edit to make the question clearer; it wasn't clear to me, being in the same code block.

Answer (score 1):

### Extending a simple type with attributes

Inspired by [Petru Gardea's answer to *XSD custom type with attribute and restriction*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11891745/413020), I have come up with a solution that should work for you. Your element must be a complexType extending the restricted simpleType with an attribute:

```
<!-- simple type that we want to extend with an attribute -->
<xs:simpleType name="populationType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="1000"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- extending a simple content element with an attribute -->
<xs:element name="population">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <!-- populationType is a simple type -->
            <xs:extension base="populationType">
                <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

### Extending multiple types with the same set of attributes

In addition, if you want to extend multiple types with the same set of attributes, you could use the [`xsd:attributeGroup`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/primer.html#AttrGroups) as suggested in 
[C. M. Sperberg-McQueen's answer to *XSD: Adding attributes to strongly-typed “simple” elements*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14497740/413020):

```
<!-- several types declare this set of attributes -->
<xs:attributeGroup name="extensible"> 
    <xs:attribute name="att1" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="att2" type="xs:string" />
</xs:attributeGroup>

<!-- simple type that we want to extend with attributes -->
<xs:simpleType name="populationType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="1000"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- extending a simple content element with two 'inherited' attributes -->
<xs:element name="population">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <!-- populationType is a simple type -->
            <xs:extension base="populationType">
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="extensible"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This would validate the following xml element:

```
<population att1="AAA" att2="BBB">100</population >
```