# How to extend built-in types with a set of attributes?

Tags: xsd

I need to extend several xml elements of different XML Schema built-in types (e.g. `xs:anyURI`, `xs:string`...) with the same two attributes `att1` and `att2` over and over again.

Example xml to validate:

```
<extendedURI att1="abc" att2="def">my.uri</extendedURI>
```

I have tried defining a complex type parent:

```
<!-- The parent type defines the two attributes I'm interested in -->
<xs:complexType name="parentType">
    <xs:attribute name="att1" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="att2" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

and then declaring the type of my elements as `xs:anyURI` and extending them, but this is not valid:

```
<!-- XXX: The following is not permitted: I cannot redefine the xs:anyURI type -->
<xs:element name="extendedURI" type="xs:anyURI">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="parentType" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have also tried to restrict the simpleContent to `xs:anyURI` and extended it with `parentType`, but I couldn't find how. Something like:

```
<xs:element name="extendedURI">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <!-- XXX: This is not permited: -->
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI">
            </xs:restriction>
            <xs:extension base="parentType">
            </xs:extension>
            <!-- 'xs:restriction' and 'xs:extension' are alternatives and
            cannot be defined at the same time!
            -->
        <xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So how could I accomplish this? Is it possible to extend a built-in type with a complexType (or to restrict a complexType with the definition of a built-in type)?

Comment: Related questions that lead me to the solution: [XSD: Adding attributes to strongly-typed “simple” elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653158/xsd-adding-attributes-to-strongly-typed-simple-elements), [XSD: How to derive a simpletype both to add a attribute to it and to restrict the acceptable value of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501094/xsd-how-to-derive-a-simpletype-both-to-add-a-attribute-to-it-and-to-restrict-th) and [XSD custom type with attribute and restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890413/xsd-custom-type-with-attribute-and-restriction)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reuse the same set of attributes by using the [`xsd:attributeGroup`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/primer.html#AttrGroups):

```
<!-- several types will declare this set of attributes -->
<xs:attributeGroup name="extensible">
    <xs:attribute name="att1" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="att2" type="xs:string" />
</xs:attributeGroup>

<!-- extending a simple content element with the two 'inherited' attributes -->
<xs:element name="extendedURI">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:anyURI">
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="extensible"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```